# Sharepoint detail item page

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I have the same problem as in this question [SharePoint 2013 - display the detail from a list item in a branded page, NOT the default SharePoint details page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655710/sharepoint-2013-display-the-detail-from-a-list-item-in-a-branded-page-not-the)
but my question is that i don't understand yet how to use this script ? 
and how can I retrieve the ID of the item from the url to retrieve his detail ? and how can I represent that informations in my page

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharePoint 2013 - display the detail from a list item in a branded page, NOT the default SharePoint details page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655710/sharepoint-2013-display-the-detail-from-a-list-item-in-a-branded-page-not-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is kind of a broad question, a more general answer

Most common ways to access/display data on SharePoint

- asp.net webpart
- asp.net page
- silverlight webpart
- sharepoint app based on javascript

with asp.net you would mostly use the SharePoint Object Model, accessing data with either SandBoxed or Form solution, by querying SPSite -> SPWeb -> SPList -> SPListItem, like

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Url to SharePoint site"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("Url to SharePoint web"))
    {
        SPList list = web.TryGetList("ListName");
        SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(ID);
        ...
        or
        ...
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">ID</Value>';
        SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);

        foreach (SPListItem item in collection) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Silverlight and Javascript either use the Rest services or the SharePoint Client Side Object Model

with Javascript you could use:
 - AJAX calls by using the odata compatible Rest services (which partly allows the usage of managed meta data),
 - SharePoint CSOM
 - The older SOAP service
 - The SPDataQuery

The odata webservice allows you to get data based on the following urls:

- lists: `http://sharepointsite/web/_api/lists`
- listdetail: `http://sharepointsite/web/_api/lists/getbytitle(%27listName%27)`
- fields: `http://sharepointsite/web/_api/lists/getbytitle(%27listName%27)/Fields`
- Items: `http://sharepointsite/web/_api/lists/getbytitle(%27listName%27)/Items`
- Specific item: `http://sharepointsite/web/_api/lists/getbytitle(%27listName%27)/Items?$filter=(ID eq 1)`

The returned data is either xml atom feed or json, based on the request headers

provided you use jquery you could use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getItem(list, id, callback) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    $.ajax({
        url: url + '/_api/lists/getbytitle(%27' + list + '%27)/Items(' + id + ')',
        header: {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        complete: function(data, status) {
            if (status === 'error') {
                // error occured
                callback(false);
                return;
            }
            var results = JSON.parse(data.responseText).d.results, i;
            callback(true, results);
        }
    });
}

getItem('listName', 5, function(success, results) {
    if (success) {
        // results is an array of objects with data
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: thx Icepickle for your scripts, so  now my page url wil be like this "http://mysite/mypage?ID=xx" so I want to retrieve the ID, so i have to retrieve the full url to know the ID value, how can I do  ??

Comment: if you use C#, you would use Page.Request["ID"]. if you use Javascript, you can use the document.location.href to get the querystring